# How to display a random photo from a folder in a picture box and print out the photo name without extension

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a folder named "MyPhotos", I want to display a random photo at each time a command button is clicked from "Myphoto" and print out the name of the displayed photo in the form without extension . I'm trying the following code, but still can't  get the photo name

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _ System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DirectoryPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Directorypath = DirectoryPath.Substring(0, Directorypath.LastIndexOf("\bin")) & "\MyPhotos"
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(GetRandomImageFilePath(Directorypath))
    picImage.Image = bm
End Sub

Public Function GetRandomImageFilePath(ByVal folderPath As String) As String
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.jpg")
    Dim random As Random = New Random()
    Return files(random.Next(0, files.Length))
End Function
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to your button method. All I used was FileInfo to get the details.

```
    Dim finfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(GetRandomImageFilePath(DirectoryPath))

    Dim filename As String = finfo.Name.Replace(finfo.Extension, "")
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(finfo.FullName)
    picImage.Image = bm
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the full path being returned by GetRandomImageFilePath.
If you want just the filename, do this in your calling Sub

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _ System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DirectoryPath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Directorypath = DirectoryPath.Substring(0, Directorypath.LastIndexOf("\bin")) & "\MyPhotos"
    Dim imagePath as String = GetRandomImageFilePath(Directorypath)
    Dim fileInfo as New FileInfo(imagePath)
    Dim imageName as String = fileInfo.Name
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(imagePath)
    picImage.Image = bm
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I just removed the extension from the 'imageName'
`Dim imageName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath)
    
End Sub`